# How to convert the column sum-function-total to dollars in Oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle

I am unable to format the below query intending to display the column-alias total re-formatted to display as dollars.  Though unsuccessful, I suspect a nested solution combined with `TO_CHAR`, is appropriate but I haven't succeeded with my attempts.

```
SELECT SUM(TO_CHAR(invoice_total,'$999,999.99')) AS "Total Invoice Amount"
FROM company.invoices;
```

Can anyone please assist?  Thank you.

Comment: `SUM(TO_CHAR(invoice_total))` does not make sense. You can't sum a varchar. You want `to_char(sum(invoice_total))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a simple-syntax issue, which I unable to see due to my growing frustration-thank you.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(sum(invoice_total),'$999,999.99') AS "Total Invoice Amount"
FROM company.invoices;
```